# About path in appsettings.json in C#

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a question concerning getting path from appsettings.json:

In appsettings.json:

```
"VirtualPathConfig": [
{
  "Realpath": "../api_website_data/images",
  "RequestPath": "/images",
  "Alias": "images"
},
{
  "Realpath": "../api_website_data/document",
  "RequestPath": "/document",
  "Alias": "document"
}
]
```

In my startup.cs

```
 var vitualPath = 
Configuration.GetSection(nameof(VirtualPathConfig)).Get<List<VirtualPathConfig>>();
  vitualPath.ForEach(f =>
  {
      app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
      {
          FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(f.RealPath),
          RequestPath = f.RequestPath
      });
  });
```

In model:

```
namespace ApiWebsite.Model
{
  public class VirtualPathConfig
  {
   public string RealPath { get; set; }
   public string RequestPath { get; set; }
   public string Alias { get; set; }
  }
 }
```

folder structure:
[image]

My question is, why can't I get the realpath out? It said Not Found!
Please, can someone give me some instructions?

Comment: Typo error. Try changing to Real**P**ath instead of Real**p**ath in appsettings.json.

Comment: I did change, but it still not found, Is that because of the path? Is the path wrong?

Comment: Also, you're using relative paths. Make sure they're relative to the correct dir (e.g. the `..` brings you up one directory, even though it looks like your `api_website_data` is already at top-level). Make sure this is correct in your output dir.

Comment: My path is "Realpath": "../api_website_data/images". Is that right? Should it be: "Realpath": ["../api_website_data/images"]?

Comment: @NPras It may be because of the path, can you tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are in debug mode settings are taking from  `appsettings.Development.json` file if it is production settings are taking from `appsettings.json`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Your model should be changed as below

```
public class VirtualPathConfig
  {
    public List<PathConfig> Paths {get;set;}
  }

public class PathConfig
{
   public string RealPath { get; set; }
   public string RequestPath { get; set; }
   public string Alias { get; set; }
}
```

Please try below:

```
var settings= Configuration.GetSection("VirtualPathConfig").Get<VirtualPathConfig>();
var realPath= settings.First().RealPath;
```

Comment: I haved changed as you said but no luck. @@ Can u tell me if my RealPath is true?

Answer (score 0):

> Startup.cs

```
                // using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
                // using System.IO;
                app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions
                {
                    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                        Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "api_website_data")),
                    RequestPath = "/images",
                    EnableDirectoryBrowsing = true
                });
```

Checkout this link for sample code: [github sample](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/main/aspnetcore/fundamentals/static-files/samples/3.x/StaticFilesSample)
Checkout this link for more info: [MS Documentation on staticfiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-5.0)